# How to remove block from magento left panel?

Tags: xml, magento, layout, magento-1.5

I have changed magento signup page layout from `1column.phtml` to `2columns-left.phtml` in `customer.xml`. I need to display only one block on my magento Signup page left panel. All other blocks should be removed from the page. Currently I am getting three magento's default blocks on my left panel with my custom block.
How to remove other blocks using xml?
Anyone Please help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`<remove name="block.name" />`

in your layout.xml

Answer (score 5):

within local.xml

```
<customer_account_login>
   <remove name="left.permanent.callout" />  

   <remove name="catalog.compare.sidebar" />  <!--product compare-->


   <remove name="left.reports.product.viewed" /> <!--recently viewed prod-->

</customer_account_login>"
```

this way you can remove whatever blocks you want to.

Comment: Any list of all the available default block names, which I can remove?

Answer (score 1):

For this you have to have use remove tag with name of block  in **customer.xml** in **customer_account_login** section

Comment: Magento will overwrite customer.xml on upgrade so standard practice is to use local.xml